# C++ entity component system framework

Tags: c++, software-engineering, component-based

I have found several entity system frameworks for other languages besides C++, like Ash and Rush for ActionScript and Artemis for Java and C#.

My question is whether there exists a framework like one of the ones mentioned above for C++?

Comment: Looks like there was a [port in progress](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1390/entry-2254064-c-port-of-artemis-entity-component-system-framework-in-progress/), but probably pretty out of date. Honestly though, the Artemis framework is not very large, it shouldn't be too difficult to port.

Comment: Agreed. I more or less made my own port of the Artemis system in C# (partially a learning experience, hence why I didn't use the current port) and it only took me about a week between work and college. C++ will be a little trickier but I can't imagine it would take much longer.

Answer (score 3):

I looked into the [C++ port of Artemis](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1390/entry-2254064-c-port-of-artemis-entity-component-system-framework-in-progress/). I was wrong about it being out of date, it's actually as recent as January of this year. It looks like the author is off to a good start. I would recommend picking up from what he's already done. It would be a great learning experience as Mike C said. If you take a look at the source for [Artemis](http://www.gamadu.com/artemis/), you'll find that it's actually pretty small, and pretty simple.

Just remember to give back to the community when you're done! I'm sure Arni Arent and Tiago Costa (creators of Artemis) would put up a link to your port on their website too. Good luck!

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the link to the C++ port. I already started my own port, but I'll just pick up from where ZBethel left off. If it turns into something I'll put it on GitHub or some there site.

Comment: Great, I plan on making my next game in C++, so a future thanks to you! Remember to up-vote if this was useful :)

Comment: I've started making a list of frameworks out there on my blog, for reference.[link](http://blog.wujitouch.com/post/ComponentEntity-System-Frameworks.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

More recently, looks like some other work has been done on Artemis ports that employ more C++ '11 features: [here](https://github.com/vinova/Artemis-Cpp) (github), which is a faux-fork of [this](https://bitbucket.org/stalei/artemiscpp/commits) (bitbucket).